# Why do fermions anti-commute in Ising model?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, fermions, ising-model, anticommutator

In my course fermions are given like a product of spin and (dual to spin) disorder parameter in 2D Ising square lattice. Then, using the properties of disorder parameter I can prove that fermions multiplies by -1 after rotating an that on the lattice fermion can be described by equation

$$\Psi^{a}_j=c\Psi_j^{a+1}+s\Psi^{a+2}_{j-a+1}$$

where upper index means direction of fermion (from 1 to 4) and down index means position on the lattice

$$\rightarrow =\vec{1};\quad \uparrow = \vec{2};\quad \leftarrow = \vec{3};\quad\downarrow = \vec{4}$$

also by solving this equation I can get that there is only one type of wave on lattice:

$$p_x^2+p_y^2=f(Temp)$$

I don't understand how obtain anti-commutating from this
[image]

Comment: I don't think you can get it from what you have given. It's a property of Fermions because they are 1/2 integer spin and so sit in a rep of the rotations that requires two full turns to return to identity.

Comment: I can get spin 1/2 from I have given (from properties of disorder operator). But I didn't get your explanation how canonical anticommutation relations are the result of spin 1/2

Comment: @AslanMonahov Look up "spin statistics theorem"

Comment: thanks, that's what i was looking for